# Apple Watch Siri cannot stop workout

Tags: siri, apple-watch

I can say into my watch: `Hey Siri, start Outdoor walk` and it will open the `Workout` app on the watch and start that specific workout.

Later I say `Hey Siri, stop workout` and this used to work - the workout would stop.

Now Siri says `I wish I could but workout is not set up with me` and I cannot see any options to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this Apple  support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204523), it doesn't appear that Siri can end a workout.

The site only show Siri starting a workout, as you've already found.   You can always submit [feedback to Apple](http://www.apple.com/feedback/watch.html)  and suggest this feature be added.